# Skype makes my processor thrash at about 25% and my fan stay on

Tags: windows-7, skype, cpu-usage

When I start Skype, task manager shows skype.exe constantly using 25% CPU and the fan on my laptop comes on and stays on.

My default browser is Chrome.

How can I stop this happening?

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 1):

Workaround: Change default browser to something other than Chrome:

Start > Default Programs > Set your default programs > Internet Explorer (or Firefox) > Set this program as default.

(Or swap Skype for something else).

[Source: http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Getting-extremely-high-CPU-usage/m-p/2104637#M202177](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Getting-extremely-high-CPU-usage/m-p/2104637#M202177)