# Reduce Skype CPU utilization

Tags: windows-7, skype

Skype (v.6.11.0.102) is consistently using ~50% of my CPU (Windows 7 32 bit) while idling. This causes my system to be less responsive and my overall CPU utilization hovers in the 80-90% (or higher) range.

I need to use Skype for work, so using something else (or just not using it) is not an option.

How can I get Skype to be less of a CPU hog?

Some further data points:

- Chrome is my default browser
- I have uninstalled "Skype Click To Call" and restarted Skype, with no improvement
- Following the advice [here](http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-desktop-client/Getting-extremely-high-CPU-usage/m-p/2115331#M203340), I set IE to be the default browser, then put it back to Chrome. Unfortunately it didn't help

Comment: is that when it is idling or during calls?

Comment: @SaUce: It happens while idling.

Comment: Do you have Chrome set as your default browser by chance?

Comment: @Ramhound: Sure do.

Comment: You might want to read this question http://superuser.com/questions/701455/skype-makes-my-processor-thrash-at-about-25-and-my-fan-stay-on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution *appears* to be to set some other web browser to be the default.

When I changed Internet Explorer to be the default browser and re-started Skype, the CPU levels stayed low.

However, this is a *sub-optimal* solution, because I don't *want* Internet Explorer to be my default browser.

Comment: some person in the skype thread (linked to in the se thread linked in comments) suggested that an earlier version which does not have/support the "ad bar" area does not suffer from this problem. Perhaps you might try identifying the ad server's IP and add that to your hosts file with a redirect to "localhost" as a test...